# Running Javascript inside Iframe without affecting the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have to add an iframe in my webpage and inside that load a widget with the use of javascript.
I have done a lot of research on this and found that this implementation affects the main page as well probably because of the other css and scripts the widget might load.
So basically in a nutshell I have only one question-
What is the best way to make an iframe element and attatch a script to that so that it doesn't affect the whole page.
The different pieces of code I have used till now,

```
iframe=$('<iframe>');
iframe[0].appendChild('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://somecode.com/code/js-widget/orderingWidget.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Error:iframe[0] is undefined.
The other one

```
var previewDoc = window.frames[0].document;

                previewDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                previewDoc.write("<html>");
                previewDoc.write("<head>");
                previewDoc.write("<style type='text/css'></style>");
                previewDoc.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://somecode.com/code/js-widget/orderingWidget.js'");
                previewDoc.write("</head>");
                previewDoc.write("<body>");
                previewDoc.write("test");
                previewDoc.write("</body>");
                previewDoc.write("</html>");
                previewDoc.close();
```

Error: window.frames[0] is undefined.
And this one, where iframe is already created using jquery and assigned id=myiframe,

```
$(function() {  
                 $iframe = $('#myiframe');
                 $iframe.ready(function() {
                 $iframe.contents().find("body").append('Test');
                 });
             });
```

Error:Affects the whole page and triggered through console and not actually the function being called.
Thanks in advance.
PS:I have used content.document and content.window.document, both return undefined.